# New Outlook mail message doesn't load

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

I have the following simplified code:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
protected void SendEmailBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Outlook.Application OutlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)OutlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Subject = "Test Send Email";
            mailItem.BCC = "test@test.com";
            mailItem.Body = "Dear";
            mailItem.Display(false);
        }
```

I've installed office 2007 and 2007 PIAs and deployed the code on the server (win2008 server), but when I click on the send button nothing happens on the clients machine the outlook mail message is not created, the page just stays in a loading state, no errors or exceptions are given.  Looking at task manager on the server the outlook process does start and is running.  The code works fine locally i.e. an outlook mail  message is created.  I'm not sure what could be causing this to happen, could it be the anti virus on the server blocking file access? Do I need to install something else?  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Change `mailItem.Display(false);` to `mailItem.Display(true);` and see what happens

Comment: Yep, Your telling the Outlook MailItem to set the display property to false.

Comment: @JMK: sorry, that won't do it, that's just indicating whether or not the mail item is displayed modally.

Comment: Is this in a web application?

Comment: @Mike Ah ok sorry, was just starting with the obvious

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Should the message be **sent**, should it be in the **Drafts** or **Inbox** folder? Please describe the specific expected behavior.

Comment: This is a web application Mike

Comment: All that i am expecting to happen is for a outlook mail message to appear on the users machine with the specfied details filled in.  Thanks

Comment: Does my answer not work for you?

Comment: Thanks JMK but still it does not work, I've just run the solution on the server and debugged, for some reason i get McAfee agent install start up and "Error 1310 Error writing to file c:\...\UdaterUI.exe" verify that you have access to that directory.  Do i need to give Network Service extra permissions on that folder though i think i should'nt have to?  Thanks.

Comment: If it's a web application does my first answer (a hyperlink) not work? As in, if you put this hyperlink onto your page, and then view the page in the browser and click on it?

Comment: That works for static content, but i need it in a click event as i need to generate the bcc list dynamically depending upon input from another user control.

Comment: Can't you then use a [StringBuilder](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder) to build your hyperlink under the click event, place a `Hyperlink` control onto your WebForm and then make the `NavigateUrl` property of the Hyperlink control equal to the string you created with the StringBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to load the message in an outlook window for the user to review and then send themselves I think that using Outlook Interop is overkill. Just use an ordinary hyperlink like so:

```
<a href="mailto:?bcc=test@test.com&subject=Test+Send+Email&body=Dear">My Hyperlink</a>
```

Or in C#:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:?bcc=test@test.com&subject=Test+Send+Email&body=Dear");
```

Comment: All I want to happen is to load the message in an outlook window for the user to review and then send themselves